# ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem() not available on PCL for MVVMCross 3.2.1

Tags: android, ios, xamarin, mvvmcross, portable-class-library

I am creating an MVVMcross Xamarin application and I am trying to spin a thread to get results from a dabate and update the list when it calls back. I have done this sort of thing before using Win 8 and iOS, but it seems that System.Threading.ThreadPool is not available the profile I am using. (Profile 259 or 79 can't remember which one I am using but it is for MVVMCross 3.2.1)

```
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(CallBack, DoStuff);
```

Am I forgetting something here or is this just not how it's done anymore.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The replacement for `ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem` is `Task.Run`:

```
Task result = Task.Run(() => DoStuff());
```

**Update**

Please note that `Task.Run` and `Task.Factory.StartNew` are not behaving the same. See Stephen Toub's awesome [blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2011/10/24/10229468.aspx) on this topic.

Comment: The alternate that I found was TaskFactory.StartNew() is this the same or just a more convoluted way of doing this?

Comment: I also frequently use `async` methods in this case - e.g. just calling an `async` method without using `await` on its result. This works well for "background work" which is mainly network IO bound, but doesn't work if the "background work" is more computationally heavy.

Comment: Awesome. Thanks for the quick and helpful response.

Comment: Please note that marking a method as `async` doesn't magically cause the work to happen on a worker thread. It only enables the compiler to allow returning values instead of tasks. The implementation is still responsible for scheduling the work.